# ThreeJS не запускается в Vite

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, vite

Всем привет. Начал экспериментировать с Vite, захотелось сделать небольшую игру на ThreeJS, используя этот сборщик. Сам сборщик запускаю на Vanilla + TypeScript.

Поставил three в devDependencies: `npm i -D @types/three`

Установилось, dev сервер запустился, но возникла проблема, когда я попробовал импортировать класс `WebGLRenderer`, на что мне выдало:

```
23:29:45 [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "three" from "src/main.ts". Does the file exist?
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: /home/.../magicians/src/main.ts
  1  |  import {WebGLRenderer} from "three";
     |                               ^
  2  |  import "./style.css";
  3  |  let webgl = new WebGLRenderer();
      at formatError (/home/.../magicians/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b5f3ba8.js:44087:46)
      at TransformContext.error (/home/.../magicians/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b5f3ba8.js:44083:19)
      at normalizeUrl (/home/.../magicians/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b5f3ba8.js:68980:26)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async TransformContext.transform (/home/.../magicians/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b5f3ba8.js:69113:57)
      at async Object.transform (/home/.../magicians/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b5f3ba8.js:44285:30)
      at async transformRequest (/home/.../magicians/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b5f3ba8.js:58557:29)
      at async viteTransformMiddleware (/home/.../magicians/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b5f3ba8.js:58695:32)
```

На официальном сайте Vite JS вычитал, что она делает оптимизированные сборки библиотек. Видимо, со Three у Vite не сложилось. Однако, что делать - хз :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю @types/three отвечает за поддержку типизации библиотеки. Вам необходимо установить и саму библиотеку тоже.

```
npm i three -D
```

Comment: Да, действительно помогло! Не думал в эту сторону, благодарю за решение :)

Comment: Только там не `--save-dev`, а просто `--save`